# Serializable remove

Tags: java, arraylist

Now I'm doing a assignment of LMS (library management system). But, I'm struggling at this part because I need to present it as OO concept so I am a little bit confused of the remove function.

The `remove` is for deleting some specific record of the book by its bookname. That remove can work but it cannot detect, so my question is how to detect it when there is no such book inside the data?

```java
public static boolean deleteBook() {
    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Find Book name:");
    int i = 0;
    for (int index = 1; i < bk.size(); i++) { 
        if (bk.get(i).getBookTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
            bk.remove(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How is the code not doing what you want already? It returns `false` when there is no such book.

Comment: How does the question relate to `Serializable` ?

Comment: What is the `int index = 1;` used for?

Comment: It can work but i dont know is my logic error or other stuff...it can remove but cannot detect. when i type something not in the data file but it still show "delete successful".so how?

Comment: @PeterLawrey that 'int index i' i dont know because i follow others code and this code is only one function of the class.

Comment: You haven't included that code. Most likely you are ignoring the result returned by this method.

Comment: A common reason for not using the code correctly because the code you have is not understood. If you used this code correctly, your program would work.

Comment: @PeterLawrey so what should i do?

Comment: Fix the code, you haven't included, which is calling this method. Without seeing it I can only assume you have ignore the return value.  If this is the case, you should not ignore it and should instead use it in a condition.

Comment: @Nicholas thank you. I will improve.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I finally fix my problem. Thank you for your suggestion.